# module not found error, permission denied(to save json)

Tags: airflow, permission-denied, directed-acyclic-graphs, modulenotfounderror

I'm a beginner want to learn how to use Airflow.
I'm trying to code DAG (data crawling - save data.json - export json file to GCS bucket)
But there are some errors with it.

First, Module Not Found.
The libraries that had the problem were 'pandasql', 'beautifulsoup4'.
change user to Airflow and do
`pip install pandasql`
`pip install beautifulsoup4`
`pip freeze >> requirements.txt`
And 'pandasql', 'beautifulsoup4' both of them exist.
However error don't gone.

Second, permission denied(to save json)
After that, I removed code using 'pandasql' and 'bs4' and import code.
Then the first error gone. But there is other error though.
I crawled data using API request. and try to save crawled json format data to .json file in my compute engine instance. But I can't. I tried other path to save but all failed with same error message.

Please help me. I will attach my dag code and error msg.

1. To use libraries, what should i do? just pip install? or make requirements.txt then add BashOperator task before crawl?
   And common question : where install or requirements.txt should be placed.
2. how to avoid permission error

[DAG.py]

```
import psycopg2
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os

import re
import csv
from datetime import datetime

import datetime
import json

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import logging

global job_num_dic
job_num_dic = {"소프트웨어 엔지니어" : 10110,
               "파이썬 개발자" : 899,
               "데이터 엔지니어" : 655,
               "데이터 사이언티스트" : 1024,
               "빅데이터 엔지니어" : 1025,
               "DBA" : 10231}

def get_wanted(JOB_CLASS_ID : int) -> list:
    offset = 0
    full_data = []
    while 1:
        url=f"https://www.wanted.co.kr/api/v4/jobs?country=kr&tag_type_ids={JOB_CLASS_ID}&job_sort=company.response_rate_order&locations=all&years=0&years=2&limit=100&offset={offset}"
        response=requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()["data"]
            if data:
                full_data += data
                offset += 100
            else:
                break
        else:
            continue
    return full_data

def get_all_wanted_jobs() -> dict[list]:
    global job_num_dic
    full_data = {}
    for item in job_num_dic.items():
        JOB_CLASS_ID = item[1]
        data = get_wanted(JOB_CLASS_ID = JOB_CLASS_ID)
        full_data[JOB_CLASS_ID] = data    
    return full_data

def crawl_save_wanted_raw_data():
    data_json = get_all_wanted_jobs()
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
    with open(f"/wanted_raw_{now}.json",
            'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        json.dump(data_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent = 4)
    logging.info(f"{f} saved")
        



dag_wanted_raw_data_to_gcs = DAG(
    dag_id = 'wanted_raw_data_to_gcs',
    catchup = False,
    start_date = datetime.datetime(2023,4,6),
    schedule = '0 1 * * *')

wanted_raw_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id = "wanted_raw_data",
    python_callable = crawl_save_wanted_raw_data,
    dag = dag_wanted_raw_data_to_gcs
)
```

[Error Msg]

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/wanted_raw_2023_07_05.json'
[2023-07-05, 07:09:42 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1318} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=wanted_raw_data_to_gcs, task_id=wanted_raw_data, execution_date=20230705T070907, start_date=20230705T070908, end_date=20230705T070942
[2023-07-05, 07:09:42 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:100} ERROR - Failed to execute job 5 for task wanted_raw_data ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/wanted_raw_2023_07_05.json'; 2099636)
```

[My Airflow environments]

1. I made GCP compute engine instance(debian)
2. install Airflow as follows
3. useradd Airflow
4. change default database Sqlite to Postgresql

default installation process
[text](https://github.com/keeyong/airflow-setup/blob/main/docs/Airflow%202%20Installation.md)

```
sudo apt-get update 
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
sudo pip3 install pyopenssl --upgrade

sudo apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev
sudo pip3 install --ignore-installed "apache-airflow[celery,amazon,mysql,postgres]==2.5.1" --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.5.1/constraints-3.7.txt"
sudo pip3 install oauth2client gspread numpy pandas

sudo groupadd airflow
sudo useradd -s /bin/bash airflow -g airflow -d /var/lib/airflow -m

...
```